# How can I stop JIT debugger stepping in on a crashing wcf service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, jit

I have a self hosted wcf web service with an UnhandledExceptionEventHandler logging any unhandled exceptions.. which happen frequently enough as I am engaged with a 3rd party technology provider who are a little buggy to be polite...

My question is; can I stop the JIT debugger being invoked after I've processed the unhandled exception? I'm doing as much as I can with the unhandled exception; I know the service is bombing but the fact that it bombed is recorded in our events db. Is there a compile switch I can set??

Comment: I've been wondering this much myself... Let's hope someone knows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN you can enable/disable JIT debugging through the Options dialog in Visual Studio - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx There seems to be also a registry hack that does the same. HTH